# I can not write a new Microsoft OU under others OU's in Windows Active Directory using JNDI

Tags: java, windows, active-directory, jndi

I tried write OU (Organization Unit) under Other OU's by JNDI inside my Microsoft AD. the LdapContext user has all privileges to do this. Follow the code:

```
 /**

 * Create the OU's for each break.
 * @see doCheckBrokenOrganizationUnit
 * @param myCtx  LdapContext 
 * @param organizationUnitSuperior i.e. "OU=foo1,OU=foo2,OU=foo3,OU=foo3"
 * @param ou - name of OU to be created i.e. "foo4"
 **/

private void doCreateOrganizationUnit(LdapContext myCtx,String organizationUnitSuperior, String ou){
    // Create attributes to be associated with the new context
    Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true); // case-ignore
    Attribute objclass = new BasicAttribute("objectclass");
    objclass.add("top");
    objclass.add("organizationalUnit");
    if (organizationUnitSuperior.contains(",")){
        String objectString[] = organizationUnitSuperior.split(",");
        for (int i=0; i < objectString.length;++i){
            objclass.add(objectString[i]);
        }
    } else{
        objclass.add(organizationUnitSuperior);
    }

    attrs.put(objclass);
    try {
        String myOu = "OU="+ou+","+this.configController.getParameter(Parameter.DC);
        myCtx.bind(myOu, null, attrs);
        myCtx.createSubcontext(myOu, attrs);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        log.info("Error to create the Organization Unit OU="+ou+" Exception: "+e.getMessage() );
        System.out.println("Error to create the Organization Unit OU="+ou+" Exception: "+e.toString()); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I receive this message:

```
Error to create the Organization Unit OU=ENSINOMEDIO Exception: 

    javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090C3E, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db1�]; remaining name 'OU=ENSINOMEDIO,DC=cp2,DC=edu,DC=br'
    javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090C3E, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db1�]; remaining name 'OU=ENSINOMEDIO,DC=cp2,DC=edu,DC=br'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3156)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:423)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_bind(ComponentDirContext.java:299)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:217)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:206)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.bind(InitialDirContext.java:177)
        at br.g12.cp2.alunosad.DAO.ActiveDirectoryDAO.doCreateOrganizationUnit(ActiveDirectoryDAO.java:271)
        at br.g12.cp2.alunosad.DAO.ActiveDirectoryDAO.doCheckBrokenOrganizationUnit(ActiveDirectoryDAO.java:236)
        at br.g12.cp2.alunosad.DAO.ActiveDirectoryDAO.doInsertUpdate(ActiveDirectoryDAO.java:288)
        at br.g12.cp2.alunosad.controller.ProcessADController.doProcessUser(ProcessADController.java:92)
        at br.g12.cp2.alunosad.controller.ProcessADController.doProcessAllUsers(ProcessADController.java:54)
        at br.g12.cp2.alunosad.controller.MainController.doExecute(MainController.java:50)
        at br.g12.cp2.alunosad.App.main(App.java:10)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Where does the `v1db1` that appears in the error message come from?  Is that the name of the domain controller, perhaps, or part of one of the strings passed into your function?  (It appears to contain a potentially invalid character at the end, shown here as the diamond-with-a-question-mark symbol.)

Comment: I don't no. I didn't pass any "v1db1", My domain is a internal test AD on my class. I 'll verify all code to identify where occurs this string. Thanks.

Comment: I checked the special character in the v1db1. My code does not any special character. This char came from Microsoft AD.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with LDAP (and never using Java) but my guess is that you can't call `.bind` on an object that doesn't exist yet. If I'm right, you should probably be specifying the value of `Parameter.DC` in the call to bind rather than `myOu`.

Comment: I did it, but the answer is the same